# How to save jQuery into local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have an add element function, which works perfectly. I just have no idea how to add this function into localstorage. Very new, could you please give a explanation?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li#order_open', function(){      
    $(this).before('<li><a href="Menu.php">New restaurant</a></li>');          
    // add to localsorage?                      
    var order_open = $('li#order_open').html();
    localStorage.setItem('li#order_open', order_open);
    localStorage.setItem($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have could be used. You can save the markup to local storage, and later retrieve it and add it back to the DOM.

Note that this snippet will not run within the answer, as the sandboxed frame cannot access `localStorage`.

```js
function appendFromLocal() {
  //This is just for demonstration purposes
  $(document.body).append(localStorage.getItem('div'));
  
  //This is what could be used to reload the element on page load
  //$('div').html(localStorage.getItem('div'))
}

function addNewItem() {
  $('ul').append('<li><a href="Menu.php">New restaurant</a></li>');
  
  var order_open = $('div').html();
  localStorage.setItem('div', order_open);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="appendFromLocal()">Append From Local Storage</button>
<button onclick="addNewItem()">Add New Item</button>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Menu.php">New restaurant</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try this and see what happens

Comment: I read the question as how can the click handler to added to localstorage? not how to set and get the html.

Comment: @jerneva Please see the updated version. I fixed a couple issues.

Comment: @BG101 Interesting, I didn't catch that intent at first but I could see how you read it that way. Maybe OP will clarify after attempting this solution.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a add element which adds a li every time a button is pressed, however, every time i reload the page it disappears, i wanted to add this to local storage so it doesn't disappear on reload.

Comment: @jerneva The answer still applies. I updated it for a clearer example based on your specific requirements. just replace `$('div')` with whatever your list container is, and make the call to `$('div').html(localStorage.getItem('div'))` on page load as I mention in a comment in the snippet.

Comment: @jerneva I suspect that this code will not help you either. You need to send the fact of item adding to the server anyway. And the server shall provide you html according to its state with the item added (or not).

Comment: Thank you all for your help! it is much appreciated, especially for the fact i am new to this. I am still working on this code as nothing is working, thought it would be simple as adding everything else to local storage is simple

Comment: Drew i am either blind, or tired but i do not see any comment in the snippet

Comment: @jerneva `//$('div').html(localStorage.getItem('div'))` on line 6

Comment: hi, i got it working using $(document). on('click' ..... thank you all. now i have to work out how not to disappear on page reload lol, wish me luck